# Ionic date, Select month in TS file form date picker

Tags: angular, ionic3

I’m trying to get month from `localStorage`, which i have saved in some other page. I want to compare months.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MMM/YY" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>

localStorage.setItem('date'+this.index, data);
```

This is how I’m getting date.

```
let data = localStorage.getItem('date' + this.index);
    let data1 = JSON.parse(data)
    for(let value of data1){
      console.log(value.date)
    }
```

Console Value:

```
2019-11-17 

2019-11-16
```

I want to select the month from this. Is this possible in ionic, or i have to use moment.js

Thank you.

Comment: ``new Date("2019-11-17").getMonth() + 1``

Comment: yup, done the same, `new Date(value.date)..getMonth() + 1`